# Filezillaでファイルが開けません

Tags: macos

クライアントPC内に仮想マシンを立ち上げ、FTPでファイルをDLしたのいですが、Filezillaでファイルが開けなくてこまっています。仮想マシン側のファイルのパーミッションは777にしており、cyberduckを使うときちんとダウンロードできたので、Filezilla側の問題だ、というところまで特定できています。

またFilezillaではファイルのアップロードはできますので、単純にDLのみができません。

```
エラー:        書き込み用に "xxxxx.html" を開くのに失敗しました
エラー:        ファイル転送に失敗しました
```

ファイルをDLしようとすると上記のようなエラーがでます。

- Filezillaのバージョンは3.9.0.6
- Macのバージョンは OS X 10.10

です。

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac のダウンロード先のディレクトリに書き込み権限が無い、ということはありませんか？ ダウンロード先を ~/Desktop などに、試しに変えてみると解消されるかもしれません。